Download All Files from Entire Site Collection using PowerShell SSOM
I need a PowerShell script for SharePoint 2013-2019 that will download all files recursively across all subsites and libraries and save them on disk, in a specified location.
Since I could not fine an answer to this question on this site, I am going to post a script here for the future.

This PowerShell script will download all non-.aspx files across the entire SharePoint site collection:
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$Site = Get-SPSite http://intranet.contoso.ca

$AllWebs = $site.AllWebs

# Create C:\intranet_files_backup if does not exist
$backupRoot = "C:\intranet_files_backup"
if (-Not (Test-Path -Path $backupRoot)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $backupRoot
}

function Copy-SPFolder {
    param (
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$web,
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolder]$folder,
        [string]$destination
    )

    $folder.Files | ForEach-Object {
        $file = $_
        if ($file.Name -notlike "*.aspx") {
            $filePath = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $file.Name
            Write-Host "Downloading $($file.Url) to $($filePath)"
        
            # Create a file stream for output
            $fileStream = [System.IO.File]::Create($filePath)
            try {
                # Open the binary stream from SharePoint
                $binaryStream = $file.OpenBinaryStream()
                try {
                    # Create a buffer to hold chunks of data
                    $buffer = New-Object byte[] 8192  # 8 KB buffer
                    while (($readLen = $binaryStream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -ne 0) {
                        $fileStream.Write($buffer, 0, $readLen)
                    }
                } finally {
                    $binaryStream.Close()
                }
            } finally {
                $fileStream.Close()
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host "Skipping $($file.Url)"
        }
    }


    $folder.SubFolders | ForEach-Object {
        $subFolder = $_
        if ($subFolder.Name -notin @("_cts","Pages",  "_private", "_w", "_t", "Style Library", "Forms", "_themes", "_vti_pvt", "Site Assets", "SiteAssets", "Translation Packages", "WorkflowHistory", "WorkflowTasks")) {
            $subDestination = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $subFolder.Name
            if (-Not (Test-Path -Path $subDestination)) {
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $subDestination
            }
            Copy-SPFolder -web $web -folder $subFolder -destination $subDestination
        } else {
            Write-Host "Skipping folder $($subFolder.Url)"
        }
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $AllWebs.Count; $i++) {
    $web = $AllWebs[$i]
    Write-Host "$($i+1) / $($AllWebs.Count) | $($web.Url)" 

    # Determine the backup path
    if ($web.IsRootWeb) {
        $webBackupPath = $backupRoot
    } else {
        $relativeUrl = $web.Url.Substring($Site.Url.Length + 1).Replace("/", "\")
        $webBackupPath = Join-Path -Path $backupRoot -ChildPath $relativeUrl
    }

    if (-Not (Test-Path -Path $webBackupPath)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $webBackupPath
    }

    # Loop through each document library in the web
    $web.Lists | Where-Object { $_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" } | ForEach-Object {
        $docLibrary = $_
        if ($docLibrary.Hidden -eq $false -and $docLibrary.IsCatalog -eq $false) {
            $rootFolder = $docLibrary.RootFolder
            $libBackupPath = Join-Path -Path $webBackupPath -ChildPath $docLibrary.Title
            if (-Not (Test-Path -Path $libBackupPath)) {
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $libBackupPath
            }
            Copy-SPFolder -web $web -folder $rootFolder -destination $libBackupPath
        }
    }
}

